# How to include multiple js file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I create new node.js project using express. my main file is `app.js` now i create second js file`socket.js` how to include `socket.js` file in `app.js`. js.i run node project as `node app.js`.but i want to run both file using `node app.js`.kindly give me solution i am beginner in node

Comment: is `app.js` and `socket.js` in a same directory ?

Comment: yes both are in same directory

Comment: I think 2 answers below correct. Do you got any error ? if have please send log

Answer (score 0):

You would want to require the file. For example:

```
const socket = require('./socket)
```

Here is a more in depth article into requiring node modules.
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8

Answer (score 0):

```
if your socket.js and app.js in root directory

var socket = require('./socket.js');
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using var to require a module. Typically you would want to use a const.